# How to detect orphaned sidekiq process after capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sidekiq

We have a Rails 4.2 application that runs alongisde a sidekiq process for long tasks.

Somehow, in a deploy a few weeks ago something went south (the capistrano deploy process didn't effectively stopped it, wasn't able to figure out why) and there was left an orphaned sidekiq process running that was competing with the current one for jobs on the redis queue. Because this process source became outdated it started giving random results on our application (depending on which process captured the job) and we got a very hard time until we figured this out..

How I can stop this from happenning ever again? I mean, I can ssh into the VPS after every deploy and run `ps aux | grep sidekiq` to check if there is more than one.. but it's not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Use your init system to manage Sidekiq, not Capistrano.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process

Comment: I do, but when a release a new version I need stop the actual process and respawn a new one.. I actually use something very similar to https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq. Or you mean that capistrano should issua a systemd or /etc/init./d command? That will require sudo also..

Comment: Correct, capistrano should call systemd to control the process.

Comment: I think systemd supports user services which do not require sudo?

Comment: Well I use monit (similar to upstart or systemd but not so well integrated into the OS).. but somehow the stop signal got lost and a new process was started that overwritted the pidfile.. how it happened, I don't know.

Comment: I strongly recommend against monit, for these reasons.  PID files are a hack and so is monit.

Comment: I know Mike.. but systemd is not exactly easy to master, and monit has email alerts that are really useful. If you know a better replacement I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: I wrote one, called Inspeqtor.