# Monit: how to alert when there is more than a process that matches?

Tags: monit

I want to receive an alert when monit detects that there is more than a process running with the same comand (because of this [How to detect orphaned sidekiq process after capistrano deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576879/how-to-detect-orphaned-sidekiq-process-after-capistrano-deploy)).

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom script to return a specific code when orphan are detected then use the check program to trigger action

```
 check orphan-sidekick myscript with path /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
   if status != 0 then alert
```